LDAP authentication successful in Superset (status 200), but frontend page displays 'Invalid credentials' error"
After Adding Ldap configuration in Config.py in superset container
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = False
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://172.28.38.168:389"
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "ou=DexterLab,dc=dexterteam,dc=net"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER ="hamza ahmed"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "Today@123456789"
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"

When Access Superset with AD user its always show Invalid login. Please try again.
below are the logs of Container
2024-04-17 09:17:14   warnings.warn(
2024-04-17 09:17:27 Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.sybase.pyodbc.SybaseDialect_pyodbc'>: No module named 'google'
2024-04-17 09:17:27 2024-04-17 04:17:27,494:WARNING:superset.db_engine_specs:Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.sybase.pyodbc.SybaseDialect_pyodbc'>: No module named 'google'
2024-04-17 09:17:27 172.17.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2024:04:17:27 +0000] "GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 48537 "http://localhost:8080/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-04-17 09:17:42 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2024:04:17:42 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.88.1"
2024-04-17 09:17:42 172.17.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2024:04:17:42 +0000] "POST /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "http://localhost:8080/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-04-17 09:17:42 Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.sybase.pyodbc.SybaseDialect_pyodbc'>: No module named 'google'
2024-04-17 09:17:42 2024-04-17 04:17:42,701:WARNING:superset.db_engine_specs:Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.sybase.pyodbc.SybaseDialect_pyodbc'>: No module named 'google'
2024-04-17 09:17:42 172.17.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2024:04:17:42 +0000] "GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 48663 "http://localhost:8080/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
I want to make a LDAP connectivity with superset and login throw those Users credentials present in a Active Directory
